# Сортировка с учётом строк в MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql

Предположим, что есть таблица со столбцом "title" и следующими записями:

```
id    title
 1    Заголовок 4
 2    Заголовок 2
 3    Заголовок 1
 4    Заголовок 3
```

Тип необходимой сортировки: по алфавиту (поле title).

Подскажите, можно ли с помощью запросов получить "предыдущую" и "следующую" записи, т.е. для "заголовка 2" предыдущей будет запись "заголовок 1", а следующей будет запись "заголовок 3"?

Одним из способов решения вижу делать полные запросы:

```
SELECT * FROM table ORDER BY title
```

получать массив данной выборки и затем уже в PHP находить текущий заголовок и получать предыдущий/следующий элемент массива.

Comment: А какое условие выборки? По первичному ключу или по названию заголовка?

Comment: Условие - по названию заголовка.

На сайте есть список товаров, отсортированных по названиям. Надо сделать переход "к следующему" и "к предыдущему" товару. Первичным ключём является идентификатор(дополнительное поле), т.е. тут оно не подойдёт.

Comment: Сохраните в переменной имя заголовка поля (ЗАПОМНИТЕ!!! в базах данных нет понятия "столбец" - есть "ПОЛЕ" и "ЗАПИСЬ", но тут Вы не ошиблись :)). Создайте две переменных, допустим, strPrev и strNext. Далее, соответственно, при нажатии кнопки (ссылки, меню...) "Следующая" - запоминаете текущий заголовок в переменной strPrev и наоборот. Запрос сгенерировать элементарно: select * where title=...{имя переменной}

Comment: Таблица: 

    id    title
    1     Заголовок 3
    2     Заголовок 1
    3     Заголовок 2
    4     Заголовок 4

Сделаю запрос SELECT * WHERE title="Заголовок 1" и ничего с выборкой сделать не смогу... :)

Comment: А у Вас существуют другие таблицы, которые связаны с данной таблицей "тайтлесов"? Связь существует по ключевым (индексированным) полям?

Comment: Да, таблицы существуют. Но в данном случае они неважны.

Comment: Месье понимает толк в извращениях. Есть вопрос: id идут подряд, т.е. idPrev = id-1, idNext = id+1 (вариант 1) или нет (вариант 2)?

Comment: К сожалению вариант 2, как это обычно и бывает.

Comment: Тогда, как говорится, не мучайте свой мозг. Для системы управления контентом (сайтом)Drupal существуют расширения, которые помогут Вам решить данный вопрос. А вообще, зачем Вы сделали магазин в Drupal?

Comment: @Вячеслав Кириченко,
похоже, что вы еще с дореляционными базами данных работаете. :-)
Скажите Джо Селко "запись" и "поле", и послушайте, что он вам скажет в ответ.

Comment: Для предыдущей:

     select title prev from tab where id = (select max(b.id) from tab a left join tab b on b.id < a.id where a.title='Заголовок2');

Для следующей -- аналогично.

Comment: @msi Фраза "Скажите Джо Селко" сразу напоминает анекдот про Неуловимого Джо (я, например, ни с какими Селками не знаком).

Comment: @alexlz, приятно иметь дело с людьми, работающими с базами данных и не знакомых с селками, дейтами, коддами и иже с ними.
Интересно говорить о футболе с людьми, которые не знают Месси, Аршавина, Барселону, Спартак...
Я знаю анекдот про неуловимого Джо, и мог бы с вами поговорить о нем на соответствующем форуме.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Выполнить нумерацию строк, например, [так](http://www.sql-tutorial.ru/ru/book_numbering_by_primary_key_values.html).
2. Для строки с номером N брать строки с номерами N-1 и N+1.

Answer (score 0):

Всё оказалось просто...

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title < 'Заголовок 2' ORDER BY title DESC LIMIT 1

SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE title > 'Заголовок 2' ORDER BY title LIMIT 1
```